# Praxis Bottom Bracket Performance on BB30 Frame

Tags: road-bike, bottom-bracket, crankset, cannondale

I'm looking at upgrading the crank (stock FSA to Force 22) and getting a Praxis BB for my Cannondale CAAD10 BB30 frame.

http://www.praxiscycles.com/product/conv-bb-sramgxp-isis-2/

It seems like Praxis espouses an outboard bearing setup because of the increased BB width and rigidity (they claim) this provides.

I'm wondering if it is in fact worth it (noticeable performance upgrade/stiffness) to use a Praxis BB in concert with a GXP crank on a frame that is *meant* to take a BB30 crank naturally?

One major, non-performance, advantage I can think of is ease of access to the bearings.  I commute daily through downtown Chicago and bike components tend to get dirty and gritty fast in this area, and others too.  I'm thinking it might be worth it just to be able to service my BB at home without worrying about special tools, bearing pushers/pullers, etc.

Has anyone had success with Praxis on a BB30 frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed that Praxis BB30 converter on my Cannondale and I will never look back. I switched to a Shimano hollowtech II crank because that's the one I had lying around.

Not only does it feel more rigid, but the bb30 was hopelessly noisy no matter how often I cleaned it, and the Praxis BB has been silent so far, the bearings seem to seal better. So yes, it's rigid, quieter, easier to clean, and my frame doesn't seem to mind. Those are my findings.

Just make sure you use the proper amount of anti-seize when installing.

[image]

Comment: That's awesome, would you mind posting a pic? What type of crank did you use?